# Fork and execlp not executing my program?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, pid, child-process

So I'm trying to create a child using fork and have that child run a program using execlp, only problem is that it isnt running... kind of. Heres my simple program

```
else if (pid == 0)
    {

        fprintf(stderr,"Child process is accessing memory %d.\n", rand_num);
        execlp("helloworld", "helloworld", (char*)0);
        printf("hi\n");
        exit(0);
    }
```

I've done some research and read that if the execution is successful, the `printf("hi\n)` wont run, and thats what happened, it wont print out hi so that means it is accessing the program right? But my program test is a simple Hello World output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and it isn't running, any ideas why?

Comment: You must check the return value of `execlp()` if an error occurs `-1` is returned and you need to check `errno` to see why, assuming that it worked because it failed to print is wrong. Every function that returns a value must be checked for errors if the function was designed to report errors in some way, for example `malloc()` returns `NULL` on error.

Comment: @iharob How do i check the return value? I tried using printf and nothing was returned.

Comment: `if (execlp(...) == -1) { /* notify the error please */ }` and try to `fflush()` the output stream -> `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: @iharob so i ran the code `if(execlp("test", "test", (char*)0) == -1) printf("error");` and nothing was returned, that means it ran the test program right?

Comment: Yes it does, try `fflush()` in the `test` program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your program is actually working perfectly.  And also, "test" is a terrible name for a command.

When you are calling `execlp("test",...)`, the kernel looks for a program named `test` along your `PATH` environment variable (that's the the `p` means in `execlp`).  It will find one in `/bin`:

```
$ ls -l /bin/test
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 37368 Oct 15 04:31 /bin/test
```

It is highly likely that `/bin` is in your `$PATH` before your current directory.  In fact, it's likely that your current directory isn't even in your `$PATH`.

The `/bin/test` program is (well, mostly was) used to implement conditional statements in the shell.  E.g., when you right:

```
if [ -f /my/file ]; then ...
```

The `[` is actually just another name for `/bin/test`.

Comment: Ah well, Kenster beat me to it while I was writing.  C'est la vie.

Comment: Okay so I changed the name to helloworld and you were right, it was accessing another program, however now it returns the error I implemented, I'm now getting
`error`
`hi`

Comment: It may be that `helloworld` is not in your `$PATH`.  Try referring to it as `./helloworld` (which means `helloworld` in my current directory).

Answer (score 0):

```
execlp("test", "test", (char*)0);
```

Is this on a unix or linux system? `execlp()` will search the command path (your PATH environment variable) for the program, if the program specified as the first argument doesn't contain any "/" characters. That's the case here, so it's going to search the command path for a program named "test".

It happens that unix systems normally have a program in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` named "test", and if you run that program without any arguments, it doesn't print anything. You may be executing that program instead of what you intended to execute.

If this "test" program that you want to execute is in your current directory, try calling `execl()` instead of `execlp()`. `execl()` doesn't search your PATH, so trying to invoke "test" would only look for that program in your current directory.

Comment: Linux kind of, Im using cygwin on Windows. Does it change anything?

Comment: @b1234 Type `test` in the command line and see if it runs, the `execlp()` is not executing your program but another program called `test` which is in the `PATH`. And why don't you do it in linux then?

Comment: @iharob Yeah I changed the name, thank you but now I am getting the error. Also I have a virtual machine that runs Linux but I find cygwin easy to use. Maybe I should start using it.

Comment: Yes it work!! I just used execl and it runs my program, thank you all so much.

Comment: You really should start using linux, when you get back to windows some day for something you will say **oh??? how was a tolerating this ...???**